# Quotient rule for higher dimensions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Find $\displaystyle \nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^{2a}}\right)$ where 
$\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash \{ 0 \}$.

I have $\displaystyle 
\frac{\| \mathbf{x} \|^{2a} \times\ n-\text{something}}
     {\| \mathbf{x} \|^{4a}}$.

Comment: Could you provide us with some more info? Like, is x a vector, what dimension are we in, what is the something you got in the second line, some more of what you tried, etc? And what is n?

Comment: x is vector in R^3/{0} and a is a real number

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  \nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^{2a}}\right) &=
  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}
  \left[
    \frac{x_{i}}{\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{j}^{2} \right)^{a}}
  \right] \\
  &=
  \sum_{i=1}^{n}
  \left[
    \frac{1}{\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{j}^{2} \right)^{a}}-
    \frac{2ax_{i}^{2}}{\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{j}^{2} \right)^{a+1}}
  \right] \\
  &= \frac{n}{\| \mathbf{x} \|^{2a}}-
     \frac{2a\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}}{\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{j}^{2} \right)^{a+1}} \\
  &= \frac{n-2a}{\| \mathbf{x} \|^{2a}}
\end{align*}

In particular, when $\displaystyle a=\frac{n}{2}$,
$$\nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^{n}}\right)=
\frac{2\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2} \right)}
\delta (\mathbf{x})$$